# Giving an element multiple names/id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have come across a few posts emphasizing that an ID is only used once.

However I need to pass 2 php variables to my javascript. I intended to use the `document.getElementById` but since I can only have one ID, this will not work.

Are there any other ways to achieve this?

My code:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="prodModal" presID="<?php echo $selectPresForJs->valueof('pres_id'); ?>" prodID="<?php echo $prod->prod_id; ?>" data-target="#prodModal" class="image_modal" >
                        <img class="image-modal" style="width: 192px; height:192px;" src="<?php echo $prod->prod_icon; ?>">
                        <span ><h2 style='color:#2468A6'><b><?php echo $prod->prod_name ?></b></h2></span>
                    </a>
```

The two variables I need to pass are the `presID` and the `prodID` variables. found in the `<a>` element.

**EDIT**

After a suggestion I have rewrote my code as follows:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="prodModal" data-presId="<?php echo $selectPresForJs->valueof('pres_id'); ?>" data-prodId="<?php echo $prod->prod_id; ?>" data-target="#prodModal" class="image_modal" >
                        <img class="image-modal" style="width: 192px; height:192px;" src="<?php echo $prod->prod_icon; ?>">
                        <span ><h2 style='color:#2468A6'><b><?php echo $prod->prod_name ?></b></h2></span>
                    </a>
```

The javascript I am using looks as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#prodModal').click(function() {


        var ajaxprodId = $('#prodModal').data('prodId');
        var ajaxpresId = $('#prodModal').data('presId');
              /*Console Prints the variables as undefined*/  
          console.log(ajaxprodId);
          console.log(ajaxpresId);

        $.ajax({

        url: "path/to/file/Presentation.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {prodId : ajaxprodId,presId:ajaxpresId}


        ,success: function(data){
         console.log("Success was achieved");
         document.getElementById("modal_content").innerHTML = "Works";
      },
      error: function(data){
          console.error("The action was unsuccessfull");
          alert(data);

      }


    });
}); 


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Leopard's answer, from a technical point of view, isn't completely correct, I'll throw my own two cents in:

On the HTML side, you use custom data attributes like so:

```
<a class="image_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="prodModal"
   data-pres-id="<?php echo $selectPresForJs->valueof('pres_id'); ?>"
   data-prod-id="<?php echo $prod->prod_id; ?>" data-target="#prodModal">
  <img class="image-modal" style="width: 192px; height:192px;"
       src="<?php echo $prod->prod_icon; ?>">
    <span>
      <h2 style='color:#2468A6'>
        <b><?php echo $prod->prod_name ?></b>
      </h2>
    </span>
</a>
```

Now, using JavaScript, you'd access it like this:

```
var product = document.getElementById('prodModal');
product.dataset.presId // contains value of 'pres_id'
product.dataset.prodId // contains value of 'prod_id'
```

Please note the difference here: HTMl specifies custom data attributes by separating words with dashes which get **automatically** "translated" into camel case variables and properties, e. g. `data-foo-id` is accessed via `dataset.fooId`.

For more in-depth information, please see the [W3C's specification on dataset](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#custom-data-attribute).

Additionally, please obey HTML and JavaScript naming guidelines by using `fooId` instead of `fooID`.

In case you want to use jQuery, you'd use this:

```
$('#prodModal').data('presId'); // contains value of 'pres_id'
$('#prodModal').data('presId'); // contains value of 'prod_id'
```

Please have a look that access via [data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/), too.

Comment: This is actually very well received. I applied Leopard's answer and have currently been struggling with my modal not being opened as I had to assign a regular id to the `<a>` tag. This solution is both better explained and it would seem better working as well.However, upon application of your solution, the variables seems to be undefined

Comment: @AlbertusBrandVenter, thanks for your updated question, I've looked at your additions and found that you're using `data-presId` and `data-prodId` within your HTML. While this is correct in JavaScript, you have to use `data-pres-id` (and `data-prod-id` respectively) on the HTML-part of your code. Please read my answer again as I exactly pointed out this convention. Also, I'd happily see my answer as the accepted one (just untick the current one and tick mine).

Answer (score 6):

You can use custom html attributes like `data-pres-id` and `data-prod-id`

```
data-pres-id="<?php echo $selectPresForJs->valueof('pres_id'); ?>"
```

You can access these variables in javascript by targetting the `a` element.

```
var ele = document.getElementById("yourelementID");
var pressID = ele.attributes["data-pres-id"].value;
```

Comment: Cool, and then how can I pass the value to my javascript?

Comment: This does not use jQuery, but instead uses plain old JS. This doesn't make much sense since the OP already showed in his/her initial code snippet that s/he uses jQuery.