# Undefined variables using html dataset id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This question is a continued one of this [Giving an element multiple names/id's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324922/giving-an-element-multiple-names-ids) question I asked earlier.The second answer shows what is the better way to go about giving a element multiple attributes.

However after applying this method to my work. My javascript variables are undefined.

My html:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="prodModal" data-presId="<?php echo $selectPresForJs->valueof('pres_id'); ?>" data-prodId="<?php echo $prod->prod_id; ?>" data-target="#prodModal" class="image_modal" >
                    <img class="image-modal" style="width: 192px; height:192px;" src="<?php echo $prod->prod_icon; ?>">
                    <span ><h2 style='color:#2468A6'><b><?php echo $prod->prod_name ?></b></h2></span>
                </a>
```

My javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){



 $('#prodModal').click(function() {


        var ajaxprodId = $('#prodModal').data('prodId');
        var ajaxpresId = $('#prodModal').data('presId');
              /*Console Prints the variables as undefined*/  
          console.log(ajaxprodId);
          console.log(ajaxpresId);

        $.ajax({

        url: "path/to/file/Presentation.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {prodId : ajaxprodId,presId:ajaxpresId}


        ,success: function(data){
         console.log("Success was achieved");
         document.getElementById("modal_content").innerHTML = "Works";
      },
      error: function(data){
          console.error("The action was unsuccessfull");
          alert(data);

      }


    });
}); 


});
```

**1.** How would I fix/change my code so that variables `ajaxprodId` and `ajaxpresId` are not undefined?

**2.** Where would the correct place be to have ajax replace the innerHTML, as the current position only works after the modal has been opened, closed and then opened again.

Comment: Your elements don't have an ID, so `$('#prodModal')` returns nothing, as expected, and hence `$('#prodModal').data('prodId')` is not defined.

Comment: ^^ + the `data-*` naming is off, capital letters are not allowed, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*

Answer (score 1):

when you use the selector `$('#prodModal')` you are referencing a DOM element with the attribute `id` set to `prodModal`. That `id` is not the same as your `data-id`.

So when you are using `$('#prodModal')` you get nothing because there isn't any element with that `id`

Comment: I suspected as much. But what is the alternative then. How could I reference the `data-id` in the same way?

Comment: `$('[data-id="prodModal"]')` would do that, but it would be easier to just change the HTML and use an ID instead of data-id.

Comment: yep, as @adeneo suggests the easy way is setting an `id` on the HTML. Change `data-id="prodModal"` to `id="prodModal"` and it's done